# Problema com arrays JavaScript na hora do donwload

Tags: javascript, array

Gurizada, estou com o seguinte problema, criei um filtro na minha pagina e toda vez que digito algo ele faz uma nova requisição para API como no exemplo abaixo, o problema é que quando eu vou fazer o donwload de tudo que veio do filtro ele entra Array por Array e baixa de todas as requisições, gostaria que fizesse o donwload apenas da ultma e não da primeira até a ultima, pois o filtro me traz digamos 2 audios e ao invés de baixar só os dois audios, ele baixa 12, pois ele baixa os dois de cada um dos array. nesse exemplo abaixo o correto seria baixar só desse array aqui:
call.js:191 teste

```
function baixarTodasChamadas(chamadas, token) {
```

const botao = document.getElementById("botaoDownloadTodas");
botao.disabled = true;

if (typeof chamadas !== "undefined" && chamadas.length > 0) {
chamadas.forEach((chamada, index) => {
// Verifica se a chamada atende aos critérios de filtro e ainda não foi baixada
if (
new Date(formatarData(chamada.iniDT)) > dataLimite &&
chamada.userID.toLowerCase().includes(filtroUserID) &&
(filtroData
? formatarData(chamada.iniDT).startsWith(filtroData)
: true) &&
!chamada.downloaded
) {
const pathFile = chamada.pathFile;
const userIDPrefix = chamada.userID.substring(0, 4);
const horaDPrefix = chamada.iniHR.substring(0, 5);

```
    const dataFormatada = formatarData(chamada.iniDT);
    const nomeArquivo = `${chamada.grupo}-${userIDPrefix}-${dataFormatada}-${horaDPrefix}.wav`;

    // Construa o URL completo para o download
    const urlDownload = `APIAQUI`;

    // Adicione o token de autorização ao cabeçalho da requisição
    const headers = {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
    };

    // Realize o download
    fetch(urlDownload, { headers })
      .then((response) => response.blob())
      .then((blob) => {
        // Crie um link temporário e inicie o download
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
          new Blob([blob], { type: "audio/wav" })
        );
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = nomeArquivo; // Use o nome do arquivo desejado
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        document.body.removeChild(a);

        // Marca a chamada como baixada

        // Habilita o botão após o último download
        if (index === chamadas.length - 1) {
          botao.disabled = false;
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Erro ao baixar chamada:", error);
        botao.disabled = false; // Habilita o botão em caso de erro
      });
  }
});
```

} else {
console.error("Erro: Nenhuma chamada disponível para download.");
botao.disabled = false;
}
}

(1000) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …] call.js:191 teste: (827) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …] call.js:191 teste: (733) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …] call.js:191 teste: (53) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] call.js:191 teste: (12) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] call.js:191 teste: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLiyX.png

Comment: Considerando que esta pergunta [já foi feita](/q/590139/70) e orientações dadas, o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta segunda postagem, mas pode ser utilizado na postagem original, basta clicar em 'restaurar' lá (e editar conforme links passados).